# Catalog price is not being updated after changes of customer group from admin

Tags: magento2

If I am logged in the front area and my

```
customer group is :-  [general]
```

After that, I create a new customer group [vendor] and create new catalog price rule for vendor type customer and assign 10% discount to vendor group customer.

Now if I change my customer group from admin 
 `general to vendor` then I am unable to find 10% discount on product price.

I did this action to find the effect:- flush/indexer/clear.

Comment: If I re - login then price will be upated.